# Insert Row Number over column into SQL table when record added

Tags: sql, insert, row-number

Hopefully a simple question. I would like to automatically add a line number when a new record is added to a sql table. The line number should be sequential, but start at 1 for each instance of a value in a separate column.

eg. I have have table:

| ID | Territory | LineNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | 1 |
| 2 | Germany | 2 |
| 3 | France | 1 |
| 4 | UK | 1 |
| 5 | UK | 2 |

If I add a new record with territory Germany, Line Number should be 3. If I add a new record with a new territory eg Spain, line number should start at 1. Once created, the value will never change, even if earlier rows are deleted.

I know how to return this in a query result set, using ROW_NUMBER() OVER and PARTITION. But what is the best way of adding it to the physical table when the record is first created? Can I use the default value property or should it be a trigger?

Thanks for any help,

Jim

Comment: Please can you tell us what have you tried ? Also, please add Database tag(of the database you are using). Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking makes sense during INSERTs, but what about UPDATEs and DELETEs?  Taking your example; Add another 'Germany' (row 6), then update row 2 to be 'UK', then delete row 4.  At each of those three stages, what should happen to all of the other rows?

Comment: @MatBailie I am not worried about UPDATEs or DELETEs in this application. Once the record is written, the partition column (in my example Territory) will never change. As I mentioned above, if a record gets deleted, all other line numbers should NOT change. (The likelihood is that records won't ever be deleted.)

Comment: @VBoka I have considered writing a function with a SELECT MAX(LineNumber) WHERE GroupID = xx statement to return a value of the maximum LineNumber value found, and then either returning that value to MS Access (the Front End) or inserting into a trigger. But I am sure this is not the best way to do it?

Comment: Is the dbms Access then? You still haven't updated that on your question...

Comment: @VBoka Sorry, the database is Azure SQL Server, with a FE written in MS Access, using a combination of linked tables and opening connections to run stored procedures etc.

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry, the database is Azure SQL Server, with a FE written in MS Access, using a combination of linked tables and opening connections to run stored procedures etc.